# Remove columns on the condition of sum in R

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I am trying to make a spam predictor. I have got the words for it.

I got the matrix where columns are the words occuring in the mails and the result that it is spam/non-spam such as

Example:-

```
mail thing money dollar spam
0     1     1     1     1
1     0     0     1     0
0     0     1     1     1
```

and so on.
The column "spam" here denotes that the mail is spam or not.

**How should I remove the columns whose sum of the column(only when spam is 0) is less than a specific value(let's say x)?**

This way I can remove the terms which are not necessary at all to detect a spam.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `your_matrix[, colSums(your_matrix * your_matrix[, 5]) >= x]`

Comment: This is a pretty crappy method of variable selection, however. Anything that is oppositely correlated with spam has information but will be removed.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
set.seed(1)

mydata <- data.frame(A = sample(0:1, 10, T),
                     B = sample(0:1, 10, T),
                     C = sample(0:1, 10, T),
                     D = sample(0:1, 10, T),
                     spam = sample(0:1, 10, T))

##    A B C D spam
## 1  0 0 1 0    1
## 2  0 0 0 1    1
## 3  1 1 1 0    1
## 4  1 0 0 0    1
## 5  0 1 0 1    1
## 6  1 0 0 1    1
## 7  1 1 0 1    0
## 8  1 1 0 0    0
## 9  1 0 1 1    1
## 10 0 1 0 0    1


mydata_ones <- mydata [ mydata[, ncol(mydata)] == 0, ]

colSums(mydata_ones)

## A    B    C    D spam 
## 2    2    0    1    0 

cbind(mydata[, -ncol(mydata)] [, colSums(mydata_ones) >= 2 ], 
      spam = mydata[, ncol(mydata)])

##    A B spam
## 1  0 0    1
## 2  0 0    1
## 3  1 1    1
## 4  1 0    1
## 5  0 1    1
## 6  1 0    1
## 7  1 1    0
## 8  1 1    0
## 9  1 0    1
## 10 0 1    1
```

Comment: I guess it takes the overall mean of the column. I want to have the mean of the column for only those values where spam is 1.

Comment: Sorry I read `mean`, not `sum`. So you want to keep columns whose sum is not less than x. I'll edit.

Comment: yeah. And sum it only when spam values are 1

Comment: I don't get what you want further, since you didn't say in your question anything more than what I did.

Comment: Ok I think I get. You want to sum the 1's in each column only if they correspond to a 1 in the spam column

Comment: Sorry, Did a silly mistake. Sum the 1's only if they correspond to 0 in the spam column.

Comment: Check now if it is what you aimed at.

Comment: Nope. It reduced the rows though. columns are still the same.

Comment: It didn't reduce the rows. Only the first matrix has less rows, but the second (the output) has the same rows as the initial one but less columns. I tried it on a fake example on my R and it seems to work.

Comment: it is still the same. run it twice.

Comment: Do you want me to share the github link of the file?